# How to get the BillingstateCode from BillingState?

Tags: apex, picklist, country-and-state

I have a requirement like,

If user enter `BillingState` manually in visualforce page then `BillingStateCode` must have to set automatically based on the `BillingState`.

I am thinking to use `MAP` in this case, but I don't know How to get the all BillingStateCode and put as a value in `MAP`

```
MAP<String, String> mapStatetoStateCode = new Map<String, String>();

mapStatetoStateCode.put(sObject.BillingState, sObject.BillingStateCode);
```

Is there a way fetching all BillingStateCode from soql ?

Can anybody guide me on this situation ?

Comment: Why not show the BillingState values in a picklist instead, as users can make typos.

Comment: @RahulSharma What i am trying to achieve is : I am getting `Quote.BillingAddress` from `Quote.Account.BillingAddress` it's working fine while inserting Quote but i when user open that Quote and Edit the Quote.BillingState it's not working properly as expected that's why i though let's make some changes in custom save method in class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can describe the field and get the state value with the
>   statecodes:

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Account.BillingStateCode.getDescribe();
Map<String, String> mapCodeToValue = new Map<String, String>();

for(Schema.PicklistEntry f : fieldResult.getPicklistValues()){
mapCodeToValue.put(f.getValue(), f.getLabel());

}
```